# webhook для twitch бота

Tags: c, twitch

Пишу бота для twitch. И думал что можно подписать на события [twitch doc](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/webhooks-reference#topic-user-follows)
Написал запрос такой.

```
#if 1
        snprintf ( data, 1023,
                        "GET /kraken/users?login=koschei_ HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                        "Client-ID: <мой клиент id>\r\n"
                        "Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json\r\n"
                        "Host: api.twitch.tv\r\n"
                        "\r\n"
                 );
        int length_of_data = strlen ( data );
        SSL_write ( ssl_hook, data, length_of_data );
        SSL_read ( ssl_hook, data_hook, 1023 ); 
        printf ( "%s\n", data_hook );
        memset ( data_hook, 0, 1024 );
#endif
```

Этот ник я для примера взял. Хотел свой сделать, но надо тестировать на другом. Я хочу получить id этого ника `login=koschei_`. И вот я получаю id. Далее я пишу такой запрос. Правильно ли я делаю что указываю его id в to_id, который мне вернул предыдущий запрос? `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows?first=1&to_id=146183693`

```
        char *buf =
                "{"
                "\"hub.mode\":\"subscribe\","
                "\"hub.topic\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows?first=1&to_id=146183693\","
                "\"hub.callback\":\"<мой ip>\""
                "}"
                ;
#if 1

        int length = strlen ( buf );
        memset ( data, 0, 1024 );
        snprintf ( data, 1023,
                        "POST /helix/webhooks/hub HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                        "Host: api.twitch.tv\r\n"
                        "User-Agent: com.xverizex.twitch-bot\r\n"
                        "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
                        "Client-ID: <мой id>\r\n"
                        "Content-Length: %d\r\n"
                        "Accept: */*\r\n"
                        "\r\n"
                        "%s",
                        length,
                        buf
                        );
        SSL_write ( ssl_hook, data, strlen ( data ) );
#endif
```

В общем вроде срабатывает, и мне на сервак приходит такой текст.

```
GET /?hub.challenge=G_3-6PnIUydT83LlV6k8jFiZu_HFZ9bkry2BFXnb&hub.lease_seconds=0&hub.mode=subscribe&hub.topic=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitch.tv%2Fhelix%2Fusers%2Ffollows%3Ffirst%3D1%26to_id%3D146183693 HTTP/1.1
Host: <мой ip>
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

И что мне делать с этой информацией? Я думал что буду получать сообщение, если кто-то подписался. Но я пробывал, я отписался от него и ничего вроде не появилось, подписался и может быть тоже ничего не появилось, только этот текст.

Comment: Я так понимаю что это использует WebSub. Он как раз работает как протокол подписчика и издателя. Вот он отправляет данные мне, что мне с ними делать?

Comment: Всё.. Разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

На такой запрос

```
GET /?hub.challenge=G_3-6PnIUydT83LlV6k8jFiZu_HFZ9bkry2BFXnb&hub.lease_seconds=0&hub.mode=subscribe&hub.topic=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitch.tv%2Fhelix%2Fusers%2Ffollows%3Ffirst%3D1%26to_id%3D146183693 HTTP/1.1
Host: <мой ip>
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

Нужно взять значение из hub.challenge и ответить вот так. Важно, чтобы это был не HTTP/1.1, а HTTP/1.0

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n
Content-Length: 42\r\n

G_3-6PnIUydT83LlV6k8jFiZu_HFZ9bkry2BFXnb
```

И тогда подписка будет принята.